# c# - Parsing Html tables and sorting the rows

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# and I wanted to parse an HTML table and sort the rows based on the first column. Below is a sample table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td> Xyz </td>
       <td> 123 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> Abc </td>
       <td> 789 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> Ghi </td>
       <td> 345 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm already able to get the values using HtmlAgilityPack but I'm not sure how I can make a somewhat key-value pair of  and  in order to sort and display them in a table like this:

```
Abc 789
Ghi 345
Xyz 123
```

Comment: try to learn from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654013.aspx

Comment: You could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML. Then you could use LINQ to order the rows:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNode firstTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
var orderedCellTexts = firstTable.Descendants("tr")
    .Select(row => row.SelectNodes("th|td").Take(2).ToArray())
    .Where(cellArr => cellArr.Length == 2)
    .Select(cellArr => new { Cell1 = cellArr[0].InnerText, Cell2 = cellArr[1].InnerText })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Cell1)
    .ToList();
```